# Google map sdk to show direction in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am using Googlemap sdk to show direction in my app, i have downloaded a sample app.I have integrated all the features to my app.But map is not showing.Below is the code which i am using.

```
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:9.96 longitude:76.31 zoom:12];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];


_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
_mapView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_mapView];

_markerStart = [GMSMarker new];
_markerStart.title = @"Raj";
_markerStart.snippet=@"2Km";
_markerStart.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

In the above code _mapView is getting as nil, is this a problem regarding api key or google map sdk which i copied to my project any idea.

Comment: Try this line: mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

Comment: Already tried this one, this code works in sample project.The problem is not with the frame, GMSMapView is nill.

Comment: I have tried same thing it works for me.. Do you have-> GoogleMaps.framework->Resources ->GoogleMaps.bundle seperatly added in your frameworks

Comment: yes i have added that bundle to my project, map is not showing

Comment: Will you please share your project with google drive.. if possible??

Comment: may i know your email id?? will share the code

Comment: The class which i used to show map is mapviewcontroller,pls look into it.Thanks

Comment: You problem is solved please remove your project link from comment.. Let me give you updates code link..It works.. For simplicity i have added real lat long changes i have done is.. added my code to your view did load which is copy from google and googleframework should be at root directory..

Comment: Hi there is small issue, regarding some library.Thank you very much.You can remove the link,if you put it as answer i will accept it

Comment: Thanks.. I have added possible mistakes with frameworks in answer.. you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your code I can say following: Might help others

1. Drag and drop your `GoogleMaps.framework` in such a way that it should be at root folder and also show in `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary with Libraries`

[image]

1. Add GoogleMaps.bundle from `GoogleMaps.framework`->`Resources` -> GoogleMaps.bundle
2. Add all frameworks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check whether all the frameworks are added. 
Go throught this link  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line also

```
_markerStart.map = _mapView;
```

and try again .. may be helpfull ....

Comment: That's not the issue,

Comment: _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];//_mapView nill checking via break point

Comment: no that's not the problem, i have given wrong key for sample app.The map is not null there

Comment: yes, but it still shows map.I have given correct bundle identifier